# What are some artificial Augmentations to stop the Illuminati's Army?

Tags: science-based, society, technology, science-fiction, earth-like

I am creating a future world where augmentations, all limbs and organs are the newest weapon by bolstering the natural human ability.  For example, arm augmentations allow for a strength twice the power of a normal grip.  In this world, guns are still being used, but those with augmentations are considered elite warriors.  The illuminati is amassing an army of conscripts and are trying to take over a country, lead by augmented soldiers(still hold regular automatic rifles), but with augmented limbs.

What are some mass produced augmentations that can counter guns on a battlefield that would be in an urban city?  Or would it be better to focus on augmented/improved guns?

Comment: This sounds more like a question about tactics and strategy. An army of body builders is not going to necessarily win over a group of trained SWAT members, for example. Famously, there have been things like war elephants, which are pretty superior to humans in many respects, used in warfare and their side hasn't always won. I don't think there is any single improvement of the human body that can be made that will significantly change the core of warfare.

Comment: @VLAZ prosthetic brain, obviously ;-)

Comment: As they say, *God made every man different; Sam Colt made them equal.*

Comment: @AlexP Sam Colt may have made mere men equal, but with cyberdyne's new range of subdermal armour plating, you can be assured of being more equal than the others.

Comment: @StarfishPrime yeah, I was thinking about this while writing the comment. I don't know - it seems like having a *seriously* augmented brain would tip the scales but that's way further into fiction than just limb replacements. I'm picturing literally inhuman levels of information processing like being able to slow down the (perception) of time at will and perhaps instant wireless communication between everybody. That sort of thing.

Comment: Augment eye-finger speed and coordination and make bullet fly faster. Dead man can't shot no bullets.

Comment: That's not really how "The Illuminati" usually work: They control from behind the scenes, they conquer by corruption and seduction instead of armies. Consider renaming your conquering cabal.

Comment: This feels rather like a list based questions.  Unless you know *exactly and in detail* what weapons and tactics you're facing, it's very hard to make specific answers rather than generic ones.

Comment: <Insert joke about an *arms race* here>

Comment: This seems like the classic we-have-an-unbeatable-weapon trap. No weapon or strategy is unbeatable. The enemy gets a vote: If your soldiers have armor, the enemy will start using armor-piercing weapons. If your soldiers have super-strength to defeat 10-ton boulders dropped on them, then the enemy will start dropping 20-ton boulders instead. If your soldiers can hold their breath for 2 minutes to swim under a barrier, then the enemy will rebuild it into a 5-minute barrier. Only in fiction is the enemy stupid.

Comment: @user535733 only in fiction is the enemy _the only stupid side_.

Comment: Honestly just making easily maintanable or replaceable body parts, that don't bleed and don't relay pain to their host, is a pretty good way to go. Assuming you have the technology to create efficient and reliable prosthetics, you don't necessarily need super strength; I'm not sure how often super strength is really useful in a gunfight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Urban warfare is a lot more complex than who got the bigger gun (or even is more accurate). With plenty of places to hide, you need to know (or predict) where the enemy is, and you can do a lot to keep the enemy from discovering you, and you really want to be in the right place at the right time.

So here is a list of some potentially useful augmentations:

- **Senses**: hear the enemy walking from a block away (and their heartbeat in the next room), see in infrared (maybe to the level of detecting warm breath of somebody around the corner), dog-like smell, X-ray vision. Also, an eye mounted on the hand, or on a small hovering drone. Also, spot exact direction of the shot from what sound heard by your ears (and those of your teammates)
- **Communication**: audio to inner ear, Augmented reality eyes showing locations of enemies seen by other soldiers or drones, brain implant letting you literally become one with your teammates, as well as command or directly control drones.
- **Stealth**: change skin tone, mute footsteps, suppress sound of breathing or heartbeat
- **Raw strength**: knock down doors, jump onto roofs (or off them), dash across open areas, crawl at 10mph, etc.
- **Armor or healing** (or just wound stabilization). First guy through the door will really need to be a tank.
- **Hacking** enemy communications and other augmentations, protecting yours from being hacked, pretending that you were hacked while feeding them false info, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Biological Armour is heavy and would slow the warriors down, modifying the soldier's [endocrine-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endocrine_system) and reactions to injury is more helpful.**

When you get injured, there are going to be several concerns:

Bleeding out:

- You need super-fast coagulation when cut or shot to prevent death through blood-loss.
- A reservoir of fluids, salts and red blood cells that can be released quickly from an internal gland to replace those lost suddenly by injury. (The human [spleen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spleen) does this to a small extent anyhow, just make the capacity bigger).

Shock:

- Normally the blood supply would shut down to the periphery (arms/legs and creeping up the torso according to severity) - this is to assure continued blood supply to the brain, this needs to be prevented. The super-fast coagulation contributes to the goal here, but a controlled reaction to limit [nor-epinephrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_(circulatory)) (nor-adrenaline) production would be necessary to prevent vascular constriction and shutdown of the limbs.

Pain:

- Pain can motivate, too much pain can pacify. Endorphins are released on injury, engineer to keep their release within manageable limits to prevent "monging out".

The thing would be to keep the soldiers [hyper-adrenalised by pheochromocytoma](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21803721) , keep them on the task they're set to and knock out the opposition.

Answer (score 1):

The Illuminati as a conspiracy are all about working "behind the scenes", sneaking about.  So stick with that.

Why augment 50 muscle-bound meatheads with super-strength and fully-automatic weapons, when you could just give 1 unassuming chef the ability to secrete a powerful time-delayed poison and slip him into the kitchen?

Or, perhaps swap the poison out for a mildly hallucinogenic sedative, which will prime them all for a brainwashing video, to convert enemy armies to your cause as sleeper agents?